# How can Change BackgroundColor item RecyclerView With using Condition

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, recyclerview-layout

how can I change color items with use condition for in recyclerview? my code does not work.

the recyclerView have a absent item and I want when absent count is 3, Item position changes.

RecyclerView Adapter:

```
 public class itemHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
 {
    TextView studentName ;
    TextView studentAbsent;

    public itemHolder(View itemView)
    {
        super(itemView);
    studentName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_txt_StudentList_StudentName);
    absentButton = (Button)itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_btn_StudentList_Absent);
    }
}
@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.recyclerview_item_student_list, parent, false);

    return new itemHolder(view);
}


public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {

    itemHolder itemHolder = (itemHolder) holder;
    String studentName = performanceStudent.get(position).getStudentName();
    int aCount = performanceStudent.get(position).getAbsent();

    itemHolder.studentName.setText(String.valueOf(studentName));
    itemHolder.studentAbsent.setText(String.valueOf(aCount));

    if (aCount == 3)
    {                     holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#D50000"));//does not work
    }
}
```

Comment: what you want to try `itemHolder itemHolder = (itemHolder) holder;` ?

Comment: defined RecyclerView items

Comment: can you post your whole `adapter class code` ? it will easier for us to understand your problem .

Comment: Also post your item layout file

Comment: I updated the post

Comment: still you can't post your whole `code` ? where is your `List performanceStudent` ?

Answer (score 0):

try this !

```
if (aCount == 3)
        {   
                  holder.studentAbsent.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#D50000"));//does not work
        }
```